# cannot use pip in python virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I created a virtualenv named `proj_env` and activated in the command prompt of Windows as follows:

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop\loan_predictor\proj_env\Scripts>activate.bat

(proj_env) C:\Users\me\Desktop\loan_predictor\proj_env\Scripts>pip3 install flask

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Python35\Lib\runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "D:\Python\Python35\Lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\loan_predictor\proj_env\Scripts\pip3.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'pip._internal'
```

I am not sure why both `pip` and `pip3` doesn't work, although it worked when I did `pip3 install virtualenv`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling pip from within the virtualenv?

Comment: I use pip to install stuff, but I don't know how I would reinstall pip using pip?

Comment: How did you install pip in the first place? pip does not normally come with Windows.

Comment: virtualenv already comes with python3. delete the old virtual env you created and do `python3 -m venv proj_env`. remember to activate it also